# Does one say "hoshana" after every verse in the "Nation Protected" hoshana said on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, hoshanos

The word "hoshana" is said before and after every verse in the weekday hoshanas.  Is this also the case in the "Nation Protected" hoshana that is said on Shabbos, found on page 736 in the Artscroll Siddur?

Comment: Note that I've been in shuls that don't day "hoshana" before and after each phrase, any day if sukkos